# Why do I keep getting a multiple definition error?

Tags: c, pong

Recently I've been working on my first game in C. (It is also my first programming language.) I finished a course ages ago and found a wonderful library called SDL2. It's great for graphics and all sorts. I've been also looking at other people's code and just been learning off of that too.

Anyway,  my error is this "multiple definition of: *function-name*", I think it's a classic error as some people have experienced it too. It seems to have problem with all the functions in "pong_function.c". I’m also using the Code::Blocks IDE if anyone’s wondering.

In my pong.c file:

```
#include "pong.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    auto unsigned int col = 0x00;

    paddle[0].x = 575 ;
    paddle[0].y = 210 ;
    paddle[0].hit = false ;

    paddle[1].x = 0 ;
    paddle[1].y = 205 ;
    paddle[1].hit = false ;

    ball.x = WIDTH / 2 ;
    ball.y = HEIGHT / 2 ;
    ball.speedX = 3;
    ball.speedY = 0;
    ball.direction = 2 ;
    int n ;

    init( ) ;
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Pong", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, FLAG ) ;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED ) ;

    load_files( renderer );
    get_text( surface, renderer );

    bool running = true;
    while( running ) {
        SDL_Event e;
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) ) {
            switch( e.type ) {
                case SDL_QUIT :
                    running = false;
                    break ;
                switch( e.key.keysym.sym ) {
                    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                        case SDLK_ESCAPE :
                            running = false ;
                        break;
                }

                default:
                    running = true;
            }
        }

        input( );
        update( );
        draw_screen( renderer ) ;
    }

    surface = NULL; // Just in case
    delete_items( window, renderer ) ;
    return 0;
}
```

In my pong.h file:

```
#ifndef pong_h_
#define pong_h_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

typedef struct {
    float x ;
    float y ;
    bool hit ;
} Paddle_t ;

typedef struct {
    float x, speedX ;
    float y , speedY ;
    short direction ;
} Ball_t ;

const int WIDTH = 640 ;
const int HEIGHT = 480 ;
const int FLAG = 0 ;
extern unsigned int col ;
int tWidth = 0, tHeight = 0, tX = 0, tY = 0;
SDL_Texture *f_text = NULL ;
SDL_Texture *p_text = NULL ;
SDL_Texture *b_text = NULL ;
SDL_Surface *surface ;
TTF_Font *test;
Paddle_t paddle[ 2 ];
Ball_t ball;

extern void draw_screen( SDL_Renderer *renderer ) ;
extern void update( void ) ;
extern void load_files( SDL_Renderer *renderer ) ;
extern void input( void ) ;
extern void init( void ) ;
extern void get_text( SDL_Surface *surface, SDL_Renderer *renderer ) ;
extern void delete_items( SDL_Window *win, SDL_Renderer* renderer ) ;

#endif // pong_h_
```

Lastly, in my pong_func.c file:

```
#include "pong.h"
void draw_screen( SDL_Renderer *renderer ) {
        // Clear screen to black colour
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, col, col, col, col );
        SDL_RenderClear( renderer ) ;

        // Paddle (player 1)
        SDL_Rect src = { 0, 0, 32*2, 32*2 } ;
        SDL_Rect dRect = { paddle[ 0 ].x, paddle[ 0 ].y, 32*2, 32*2 } ;
        SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, p_text, &src, &dRect ) ;

        // Paddle (player 2)
        SDL_Rect src2 = { 0, 0, 32*2, 32*2 } ;
        SDL_Rect dRect2 = { paddle[ 1 ].x, paddle[ 1 ].y, 32*2, 32*2 } ;
        SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, p_text, &src2, &dRect2 ) ;

        // Ball
        SDL_Rect bRect = { 0, 0, 32, 32 } ;
        SDL_Rect bRect2 = { ball.x, ball.y, 32, 32 } ;
        SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, b_text, &bRect, &bRect2 ) ;

        // Font
        SDL_Rect dstRect = { tX, tY, tWidth, tHeight } ;
        SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, f_text, NULL, &dstRect ) ;

        SDL_RenderPresent( renderer ) ;
}

void update( void ) {
    // Nothing yet...
}

void load_files( SDL_Renderer *renderer ) {
    if( ( surface = IMG_Load( "paddle.png" ) ) == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to load file\n" ) ;
        exit(-1);
    }
    p_text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surface ) ;

    if( ( surface = IMG_Load( "ball.png" ) ) == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to load file\n" ) ;
        exit( -1 ) ;
    }
    b_text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surface ) ;
}

void input( void ) {
    // Input
    const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState( NULL ) ;
    if( state[SDL_SCANCODE_A] ) paddle[ 0 ].y++;
    if( state[SDL_SCANCODE_D] ) paddle[ 0 ].y--;

    if( state[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] ) paddle[ 1 ].y++;
    if( state[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] ) paddle[ 1 ].y--;
}

void init( void ) {
    // Init random
    srand( time( NULL ) ) ;

    // Init TTF
    TTF_Init( ) ;

    // Init PNG
    IMG_Init( IMG_INIT_PNG ) ;

    // Init SDL
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to initialise SDL: %s", SDL_GetError() );
        exit( -1 ) ;
    }
}

void get_text( SDL_Surface *surface, SDL_Renderer *renderer ) {
    const char *string = "Welcome to pong!" ;
    SDL_Color clr = { 255, 255, 255 } ;
    test = TTF_OpenFont( "slkscr.ttf", 25 ) ;
    surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(test, string, clr);
    f_text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_QueryTexture( f_text, NULL, NULL, &tWidth, &tHeight ) ;
}

void delete_items( SDL_Window *win, SDL_Renderer* renderer ) {
    // Delete items
    SDL_DestroyTexture( f_text ) ;
    SDL_DestroyTexture( b_text ) ;
    SDL_DestroyTexture( p_text ) ;
    TTF_CloseFont( test ) ;

    SDL_FreeSurface( surface ) ;
    SDL_DestroyWindow( win ) ;
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( renderer ) ;

    SDL_Quit( );
    IMG_Quit( );
    TTF_Quit( );
}
```

Comment: @C coder All, variable declarations in the header without extern (except constant variables) are defined in each module where the header is included.

Comment: I don't see any reason in the code presented for the compiler to complain about multiple definitions of any *function*.  If that's indeed what you're getting, then the issue is probably related to your project configuration in CodeBlocks.  But as @VladfromMoscow observed, you do have multiple definitions of *variables*.  You'll find multiple questions and answers about that here on SO.

Comment: Unrelated, but declaring functions as `extern` is superfluous.

Comment: @EugeneSh. As is declaring a local variable as `auto`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: C++ has the 'except constant variables' exception — C does not.

Comment: @Eugene Sh @Christian Gibbsons, declaring a local variable with storage class auto is not a problem. I’d say I used it correctly. but ```extern``` I can understand.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, okay so that means every variable should be declared as extern. Thanks for the input, hopefully it’ll clear things up nicely!

Comment: @John Bollinger Thanks John!

Comment: That doesn't work though, having extern before the actual declaration of the prototype function isn't a problem. I feel like it's normal to do that. However, the local variable thing possibly. Since then I've made some changes to the code and have still received the same error. I'm using Codeblocks and I've checked if the header is being compiler (not linked). Somethin just doesn't make sense.